# Get attribute on right-click with a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, attributes, contextmenu

I got a problem here with a jQuery Plugin.

I want to get the attribute "photoId" from the image which the contextmenu has been called on so I can put an option in the menu like 'Delete (photoId)'.

In other words: I right-click on .imgPrev (see html below), I want the attribute photoId to be used in the menu.

Here is the plugin: [jQuery ContextMenu Plugin](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php)

Code:

```
$('.imgPrev').contextMenu(menu,{beforeShow: function() { 
                    alert($('.imgPrev').attr('photoId'));
                    return true;
                }});
```

Images are like :

```
<div class="imgPrev"><img str="..." photoId="541"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

old question however below is the solution for anyone else who might have to deal with this issue

You need to replace **.imgPrev** selector with **this.target**

```
$('.imgPrev').contextMenu(menu,{beforeShow: function() { 
                alert($('.imgPrev').attr('photoId'));
                return true;
            }});
```

with

```
$('.imgPrev').contextMenu(menu,{beforeShow: function() { 
                alert($('this.target').attr('photoId'));
                return true;
            }});
```

Comment: i think **$('this.target')** should be **$(this.target)**